# How to use the treadmill to be fit and healthy without losing muscle and shape?

Tags: workout, health, treadmill

I'm male, 29 years old, 72kg, 172cm height.
First of all, I don't like to look skinny. I just need to stay fit. I have a treadmill and a situp machine, I just wanted to find out what is the best training to follow?

Comment: With the info provided it’ll be tough to help. Just balance aerobic exercise with strength training and healthy caloric intake with exercise. Most running should be at a tempo pace with occasional (e.g., weekly) speed and hill sessions.

Comment: How will you define what is fit? Then we can better help you determine a realistic goal to reach your definition of “fit”. Looking muscular ? Vascular? Or athletic?

Comment: If you value your belly, just eat more, cardio won't make you slim if you eat more than you burn.

Comment: What's yoru bf? You have a decent weight/height.